# C# trying to read XML and stop at a certain point

Tags: c#, xml

I have a somewhat large XML file (Posted below) that I'm trying to read using C#. I have it to a point where it will read the NAME and TYPE inside of the XML file (which I will be using later) but I want to find a way when it gets to a certain tag to stop.

For example:

I have it now looking into DATA ATTRIBUTES PHYSICAL ATTR, and then looping to get all of the NAME and TYPE values.

I want it to stop when it gets to negativePhysical, because that is information for something else.

Here is the code I've been using thusfar:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("/Attributes.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("data");
                reader.ReadToFollowing("attributes");
                reader.ReadToFollowing("physical");
                reader.ReadToFollowing("attr");

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("name");
                        name = reader.ReadString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("type");
                        type = reader.ReadString();

                    }


            }
```

And here is a small sample of the XML that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <attributes>
        <physical>
            <attr>
                <name>Aggressive</name>
                <type>Unk</type>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Agile</name>
                <type>Msc</type>
            </attr>
        </physical>
        <negativePhysical>
            <attr>
                <name>Clumsy</name>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Cowardly</name>
            </attr>
        </negativePhysical>
        <social>
            <attr>
                <name>Alluring</name>
                <type></type>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Beguiling</name>
                <type></type>
            </attr>
        </social>
        <negativeSocial>
            <attr>
                <name>Bestial</name>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Callous</name>
            </attr>
        </negativeSocial>
        <mental>
            <attr>
                <name>Alert</name>
            <type></type>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Analytical</name>
                <type></type>
            </attr>
        </mental>
        <negativeMental>
            <attr>
                <name>Deceitful</name>
            </attr>
            <attr>
                <name>Forgetful</name>
            </attr>
        </negativeMental>
    </attributes>
</data>
```

Eventually each "Attribute" will be iterated through, and I will be adding more info later on into the file for "Abilities". I've looked into the code to try to use LINQ on this, but so far I've fallen flat on getting anything returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `XmlDocument` in order to read. You can iterate over the `XmlNode` elements and check the `ElementName`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.ElementName == "x")
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. When I put in `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument.LoadXml("/Attributes.xml");` it gives me the error ('System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'), and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: `LoadXml` reads XML from a `string`. Try `Load` instead. It reads from file.

Comment: I just found that on another post here, thank you. I'm going to play with this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Using what you suggested along with a few other things I found, I got it to work! Thank you so much for your help!